# How to authorize access to api? React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am trying to make a single page web app where user can search photos from Unsplash.com. I am using unsplash api and can't figure out how to get through authorization. I have no experience with authorization.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Unsplash, { toJson } from 'unsplash-js';
import './App.css';

const unsplash = new Unsplash({
  applicationId: aplicationId,
  secret: secret,
  callbackUrl: callbackUrl,
  headers: {
    "Accept-Version": "v1"
  }
});

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const authenticationUrl = unsplash.auth.getAuthenticationUrl([
      "public",
      "read_user",
      "write_user",
      "read_photos",
      "write_photos"
    ]);
    location.assign(authenticationUrl);
    unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code)
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        //console.log(unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code))
        unsplash.auth.setBearerToken(json.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log('Auth err', err));

  }



    handleClick() {
    let query = document.getElementById('input').value;
    unsplash.search.photos(query, 1) //function provided by api
      .then(toJson)
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <form id='form'>
          <input type='text' id='input' ></input>
          <input type='submit' id='submit' onClick={this.handleClick} ></input>
        </form>
        <div id='field' >
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also did everything by following these api instructions https://github.com/unsplash/unsplash-js

Comment: The API seems to need OAuth authentication. You need a server of your own. [You can read more about it here](https://unsplash.com/documentation#authorization).

Comment: ok. But I can see there is some stuff that you can do with API without authentication. but when I remove the `componentWillMount()` and I try to search for an image it says that CORS request failed

Comment: For search photo, I think you should use `unsplash.search.photos("dogs", 1)
  .then(toJson)
  .then(json => {
    // Your code
  });` in api instructions. In your code, you get token authorized but it is in unsplash object. Normally when calling API you have to set bearerToken in Url header so server can recognize, your fetch just call it normally without token in header.

Comment: Yeah, you can look now I edited the onClick function but now it tells me that the query is not defined and location is unexpected `./src/App.js
  Line 29:  Unexpected use of 'location'  no-restricted-globals
  Line 30:  'query' is not defined        no-undef` also, ater it shows these errors it rredirects me to the authentication code. how do I get that code to go to query.code?

Comment: You're missing 'query' local variable in componentDidMount

Comment: Your line 29 is `unsplash.auth.userAuthentication(query.code)`. You haven't define query in ComponentDidMount yet

Comment: how do I define it? do I define it as input from the input element?

Comment: `After the user authorizes your app she'll be redirected to your callback url with a code querystring present. Request an access token using that code.` After authen and redirected, there will be code in your Url. You can take that code to use in `userAuthentication` function.

Comment: I tried to define `query` as `location.assign(authenticationUrl)`, but it still wont work. I really dont know what I am doing here. Maybe you could show me some sort of example?

Comment: From the document, after authenticated, there will be a code in your Url. Take it and set it to your query